# BitMapFactory to increase the size of the image if required

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I was going through the BitmapFactory and found out that we can reduce the size of the image if it is higher than our desired size to avoid Out of Memory Exception. But what is the way to increase the height+width. Currently I am doing with Bitmap.createScaledBitmap..

Below is the code:

```
package sudipta.deb.imagedisplayer;

import sudipta.deb.image.ImageSources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final String IMAGE_TAG = "Image Tag";
    private final int PREFERRED_HEIGHT = 400;
    private final int PREFERRED_WIDTH = 533;
    private static int imageIndex;
    private int totalImages;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        ImageSources.configureImages();
        imageIndex = 0;
        totalImages = ImageSources.totalImages();

        imageView = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1));
        imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private Bitmap checkBitmapDetails(int index) {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                ImageSources.getImageId(index), options);

        int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
        int imageWidth = options.outWidth;

        Log.i(IMAGE_TAG, "Image: " + index);
        Log.i(IMAGE_TAG, "Image Height: " + imageHeight);
        Log.i(IMAGE_TAG, "Image width: " + imageWidth);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, PREFERRED_WIDTH,
                PREFERRED_HEIGHT);

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                ImageSources.getImageId(index), options);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, PREFERRED_WIDTH,
                PREFERRED_HEIGHT, false);
        return bitmap;
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
            // keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageView1:
            imageIndex++;
            if (imageIndex >= totalImages) {
                imageIndex = 0;
            }
            Log.i(IMAGE_TAG, "Loading Image: " + imageIndex);
            bitmap = checkBitmapDetails(imageIndex);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Do you have any information to do this in better way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could stretch it using `ImageView` parameters like `scaleType` and `adjustViewBounds` but this is workd while displaying it on the screen. However if you want to just resize the bmp here you go:

```
 /**
  * Returns given @Bitmap resized the to given size.
  * 
  * @param bm : Bitmap to resize.
  * @param newHeight : Height to resize.
  * @param newWidth : Width to resize.
  * @return Resized Bitmap.
  */
public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int newHeight, int newWidth) {

    if (bitmap == null || newHeight<0 ||  newWidth<0 || newHeight+newWidth==0)
        return null;

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = null;
    final int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    final int width = bitmap.getWidth();

    if (newHeight==0)
        newHeight = (int)((float)newWidth * (float)height / (float)width);

    if (newWidth==0)
        newWidth = (int)((float)newHeight * (float)width / (float)height);

    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;

    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    try {
        // recreate the new Bitmap
        resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
        // resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, newWidth, // newHeight, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        android.util.Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        resizedBitmap = null;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        android.util.Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        resizedBitmap = null;
    } 

    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution to handle the situation.
What I did is that if the image size if bigger than the preferred size, then first reduce the size and after that use createScaledBitmap to scale the image to exact size.

```
private Bitmap checkBitmapDetails(int index) {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                ImageSources.getImageId(index), options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, PREFERRED_WIDTH,
                PREFERRED_HEIGHT);

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                ImageSources.getImageId(index), options);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, PREFERRED_WIDTH, PREFERRED_HEIGHT, true);
        return bitmap;
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;

        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
            // keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

createScaledBitmap causes a situation where both bitmaps (original and enlarged) exist, which could cause OOM on some cases (depends on the heap size and the size of the bitmpaps).

if possible, try to use only the original on an enlarged imageview.

if you wish, you can try out a library i've made to overcome the memory issue of having 2 bitmaps at the same time, [**here**](http://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AndroidJniBitmapOperations) (post about it [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250951/jni-bitmap-operations-for-helping-to-avoid-oom-when-using-large-images)).