# JniBitmapOperations rotation causes image corruption

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation, image-rotation

i'm developing an app i which users can upload images from the camera to an event, i did it in the usual way, but when i got to the part of rotating it according to the Exif interface i would sometimes get OOM errors, which were really frustrating, i decided to try and use [JniBitmapOperations library](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AndroidJniBitmapOperations)
which seemed to work fine (i wouldn't get OOM errors) but when trying to rotate the image it gets corrupt and messed up :/ heres pictures

[image]

[image]

as you can see the picture above is rotated to the correct position but is all corrupt
the one below is the original

here is the part of the code that is relevant:

```
        Options options = new Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            options.inPreferredConfig = Config.ARGB_8888;
            Bitmap srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempImageFilePath, options);

            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options);

            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempImageFilePath, options);

            ImageLoader.getInstance().clearMemoryCache();
            ImageLoader.getInstance().clearDiscCache();
            final JniBitmapHolder bitmapHolder = new JniBitmapHolder(srcBitmap);
        //if we comment this part out, the image comes out fine but not rotated correctly
            switch (angleFix) {
            case 90:
                bitmapHolder.rotateBitmapCw90();
                break;
            case 180:
                bitmapHolder.rotateBitmapCw90();
                bitmapHolder.rotateBitmapCw90();
                break;
            case 270:
                bitmapHolder.rotateBitmapCcw90();
                break;
            }

            srcBitmap = bitmapHolder.getBitmapAndFree();
//this is the old way which caused OOM errors occasionally
            // Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBitmap, 0, 0, srcBitmap.getWidth(), srcBitmap.getHeight(), m, true);

            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempImageFilePath);
                srcBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (srcBitmap != null) {
                GetImageUploadUrl getUrl = new GetImageUploadUrl();
                getUrl.execute();
            }
        }
    }
```

i would appreciate any help!

Comment: seems like i have a bug. weird that i didn't notice it, and that it worked fine with resources. now that i think about it, it looks like an old bug i have already fixed in the past. maybe i forgot to commit. the code will currently only work if width==height. will soon fix it and tell you about it.

Comment: sorry for this. i was really sure you are to blame since i've tested it so many times. i really hope i can re-"capture" the bug i had and fix it in short time.

Comment: haha no worries, your library saved me, if i had to do it myself it would take me ages... so thank you! :)

Comment: i'm having some issues with eclipse/JNI/NDK . this could take a while . if you are in a hurry, i think the problem is with height/width mixed up in the JNI side, or something similar (since if they are equal the bug doesn't appear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, the bug was with setting the wrong width and height for the rotation functions.

i've now updated the code. now it should work.

I am very sorry for this bug. was sure that i've fixed it before. i've now added the ability to also rotate by 180 degrees, so that you won't need to rotate twice (a little more efficient).

and just to say that the sample code wasn't for nothing, here's a nicer sample code.

it will go over all of your camera images, and rotate them in any of the 3 ways, and put the result files into Android/data/PACKAGE_NAME .

here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
  {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final File picFolder=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
    final int screenWidth=getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    final int screenHeight=getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    final File outputDir=getExternalFilesDir(null);
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(this,"please wait","processing");
    new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>()
      {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params)
          {
          final File[] listFiles=outputDir.listFiles((FileFilter)null);
          for(final File file : listFiles)
            file.delete();
          final List<String> imageFilesPaths=new ArrayList<String>();
          getPicturesPaths(picFolder.getAbsolutePath(),imageFilesPaths);
          final JniBitmapHolder bitmapHolder=new JniBitmapHolder();
          int i=0;
          final Options options=new Options();
          for(final String filePath : imageFilesPaths)
            {
            options.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
            options.inPreferredConfig=Config.ARGB_8888;
            prepareForDownsampling(options,screenWidth,screenHeight);
            Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath,options);
            bitmapHolder.storeBitmap(b);
            b.recycle();
            switch(i++%3)
              {
              case 0:
                bitmapHolder.rotateBitmapCw90();
                break;
              case 1:
                bitmapHolder.rotateBitmap180();
                break;
              case 2:
                bitmapHolder.rotateBitmapCcw90();
                break;
              }
            b=bitmapHolder.getBitmapAndFree();
            final File imageFile=new File(outputDir.getAbsoluteFile()+File.separator+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
            imageFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            FileOutputStream stream=null;
            try
              {
              stream=new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
              b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG,80,stream);
              stream.flush();
              stream.close();
              }
            catch(final Exception e)
              {
              e.printStackTrace();
              }
            finally
              {
              if(stream!=null)
                try
                  {
                  stream.close();
                  }
                catch(final IOException e)
                  {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
            }
          return null;
          }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void result)
          {
          super.onPostExecute(result);
          progressDialog.dismiss();
          finish();
          }
      }.execute();
    }

  private static void prepareForDownsampling(final Options bitmapOptions,final int reqWidth,final int reqHeight)
    {
    final int inSampleSize=calculateInSampleSize(bitmapOptions,reqWidth,reqHeight);
    // as much as possible, use google's way to downsample:
    bitmapOptions.inSampleSize=1;
    bitmapOptions.inDensity=1;
    bitmapOptions.inTargetDensity=1;
    bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds=false;
    while(bitmapOptions.inSampleSize*2<=inSampleSize)
      bitmapOptions.inSampleSize*=2;
    // if google's way to downsample isn't enough, do some more :
    if(bitmapOptions.inSampleSize!=inSampleSize)
      {
      // downsample by bitmapOptions.inSampleSize/originalSampleSize .
      bitmapOptions.inTargetDensity=bitmapOptions.inSampleSize;
      bitmapOptions.inDensity=inSampleSize;
      }
    }

  public static int calculateInSampleSize(final BitmapFactory.Options options,final int reqWidth,final int reqHeight)
    {
    final int height=options.outHeight;
    final int width=options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize=1;
    if(height>reqHeight||width>reqWidth)
      {
      final int heightRatio=Math.round((float)height/(float)reqHeight);
      final int widthRatio=Math.round((float)width/(float)reqWidth);
      inSampleSize=heightRatio<widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
      }
    return Math.max(inSampleSize,1);
    }

  private static void getPicturesPaths(final String path,final List<String> filesPaths)
    {
    final Options options=new Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
    File f=new File(path);
    if(f.isFile())
      {
      BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,options);
      if(options.outHeight>=0&&options.outWidth>=0)
        filesPaths.add(path);
      return;
      }
    if(!f.isDirectory())
      return;
    final String[] childrenPaths=f.list();
    for(final String fileName : childrenPaths)
      {
      if(fileName.startsWith("."))
        continue;
      f=new File(path+File.separator+fileName);
      final String fullFilePath=f.getAbsolutePath();
      if(f.isFile())
        {
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fullFilePath,options);
        if(options.outHeight>=0&&options.outWidth>=0)
          filesPaths.add(fullFilePath);
        continue;
        }
      getPicturesPaths(fullFilePath,filesPaths);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. I've now updated the library to have an additional way to resize images, and you can also see that it has some helper functions for handling colors, so you can make your own image filters.