# Rotating bitmaps in android using JNI Library

Tags: android, bitmap, android-ndk

Please help me to solve this problem. I didn't find any stuff regarding to my problem.
I have successfully implemented rotation code for bitmap using JNI library followed by [steps-  which i followed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250951/jni-bitmap-operations-for-helping-to-avoid-oom-when-using-large-images). With the help of these steps, i got rotated bitmap from JNI library. But when i saved rotated bitmap in to SD card, image size almost doubles like 4MB image turns into 8MB image with same quality.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Code:

```
        JniBitmapHolder bitmapHolder = new JniBitmapHolder();
        bitmapHolder.storeBitmap(For_rotate_img);

        For_rotate_img.recycle();

        if (rightRotation == true) {
            bitmapHolder.rotateBitmapCw90();
        } else if (leftRotation == true) {
            bitmapHolder.rotateBitmapCcw90();
        }

        scaledBitmapNN = bitmapHolder.getBitmapAndFree();

        if (scaledBitmapNN != null) {
            // if (pDialog_rotation != null) {
            // pDialog_rotation.dismiss();
            // }
            SaveRotatedIamge(img_path, scaledBitmapNN);
        } else {

            // if (pDialog_rotation != null) {
            // pDialog_rotation.dismiss();
            // }

            someError = true;

        }
```

Comment: Probably, you convert a **rgb565** bitmap with 16 bit per pixel to **argb8888** with 32 bit per pixel.

Comment: @AlexCohn Cohn - Thanks for answer.  I will check this point.

Comment: @AlexCohn Cohn - I have trid your suggestion. i have changed 32 bit to 16 bit of jni code (uint32_t to uint16_t). Its does not increase size but image colors is destroyed. Any suggestion for this problem?

Comment: The functions you use are all tuned for 32-bit bitmaps, see the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18250952/192373) carefully. You will need to develop similar ones for 16-bit.

Comment: @AlexCohn -  thanks for information. I will take appropriate decision on this problem.